# How do I get the value from HTML/JADE input without ?"name" = "value"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I'm currently creating a searchpage where I can get my users' profiles by ID.

This is my JADE form where I put my users' ID and then I submit the form to send a post:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>List Funcionários</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/admin/css/main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1 id="title" class="inline"><img id="logo" src="/admin/image/logo4.png" alt="Image failed to load" class="inline"/>User Med</h1>
      <h2 id="stitle">Search User</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="do">
      <form id="search-theme-form" action="/profileuser/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" name="search-theme-form" class="myDform">
        <label>User ID:
          <input id="inputDoc" name="id" required="" value="" type="text" class="input"/>
        </label>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="./admin/scripts/profileuser.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JS code where I try to get my input value and change the form action `/profileuser/` to `/profileuser/"userid"`:

```
 let docid = document.getElementById('inputDoc').value;
let form = document.getElementsByClassName('myDform');


form.addEventListener('submit', submit);

function chgAction(){
    alter(docid)
    form.chgAction = docid.value;
}


function submit (e){
    chgAction();
}
```

The problem is that I can't get only the user ID from input, instead I get `?id= "userid"`.

Comment: arrt() is a jQuery method it didnt work

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but Jade was renamed Pug many years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed

`form.chgAction = docid.value;`

with

`form.action = form.action+docid.value;`

```js
document.getElementById('search-theme-form').addEventListener('submit',chgAction);

function chgAction(){

  let docid = document.getElementById('inputDoc');
  let form = document.getElementById('search-theme-form');
 
  form.action= form.action+docid.value;
  console.log("path after: "+form.action);

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>List Funcionários</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/admin/css/main.css"/>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1 id="title" class="inline"><img id="logo" src="/admin/image/logo4.png" alt="Image failed to load" class="inline"/>User Med</h1>
      <h2 id="stitle">Search User</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="do">
      <form id="search-theme-form" action="/profileuser/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" name="search-theme-form" class="myDform">
        <label>User ID:
          <input id="inputDoc" name="id" type="text" class="input" required/>
        </label>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ppfernandes oops, my bad. Changed it to JavaScript one

Comment: the problem is i cant put the inout value inside the route

Comment: @ppfernandes i think my code will append id to existing action of form

Comment: @ppfernandes Also what does `alter(docid)` doing exactly ?

Comment: its an alert() but i fix that in my code sorry about that

Comment: @ppfernandes does this `form.action= form.action+docid.value;` not working for you?. I don't see any reason why it should not work

Comment: the method is working but its not giving me the right values its should give me  localhost:8080/profileuser/1 and i getting localhost:8080/profileuser/?id=1

Comment: @ppfernandes can you please paste simple html form generated by JADE, so that i can check where we are going wrong. I think you are doing something wrong with global scope, i am modifying code, please try that code

Comment: @ppfernandes Please tell output of my last edited code

Comment: ur code did not output anyting and i update my question

Comment: @ppfernandes You HTML code is not plain HTML, copy from browsers' view source. Paste what are you getting in browser not what you have written

Comment: @ppfernandes lot of mistakes were there , it is working now,  enjoy your life man !!

Comment: @ppfernandes Please do not forget to upvote and accept it if it is working for you. Thank !!

Comment: i already fix it but your answer seems work to so i will accept and upvote you answer thanks man for your time to help